# How to keep the button "Control" pressed?

Tags: c#, .net, autohotkey

How to emulate the event of keeping the button "Control" down, from .Net?

I'm trying `SendKeys.SendWait("{Ctrl Down}");` as described here:

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

But it is not working (it says the command is not recognized).

Just clarify I dont want to perform command such <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+some other key ... I would like to have only the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> pressed all the time.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This is neither C# nor .net; it is AutoHotkey, which has its own macro language.

Comment: He is not using AutoHotKey he is trying to emulate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Autohotkey, this script does what you want:

```
Send,{Ctrl DOWN}
```

You can get out of that state by manually pressing and releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

You appear to be conflating C# with Autohotkey, however. If you are trying to use the information on that linked page with C#, it isn't going to work. Autohotkey scripts are not C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can't emulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> pressed all the time, you must add the ^ to each Send command, like this:

```
SendKeys.Send("^{DOWN}");
```

see the doc here: [SendKeys.Send Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The .Net `SendKeys` class cannot do everything AutoHotkey can do.

It can only do what is listed here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx

You can achieve what you want but only using more advanced programming techniques.

You may have to use Windows UI automation:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx